# Package : cx_Oracle for Python 3.5, windows64 bit. Oracle 11.2.0.1.0

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-3.5

I am trying to install cx_Oracle on my windows PC. I ran following command in command prompt:

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Collecting cx-Oracle
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx-Oracle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cx-Oracle
```

I am using ***windows 64bit*** machine and ***Python 3.5(Anaconda3)***. Intsalled Oracle vcersion on my PC is  ***Oracle 11.2.0.1.0*** and oracle-instantclient version ***oracle-instantclient-11.2.0.4.0-0***

Please let me know what am I missing. Should I downgrade my python version to 3.4? If yes, than how to do it using command line in Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got past this issue by following these steps:

**Create a Python 3.4 environment**

Windows + R to open Run

*Type* 'cmd' *(no apostrophes) and hit enter to open the command prompt.*

*Type the following:*

```
$ conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

**Activate and update the new environment**

```
$ activate py34    
$ conda update conda
```

**Uninstall and reinstall the qt aspect of Spyder**

*This step fixes a qt issue with Spyder when trying to open from your py34 environment*

```
$ conda remove qt --name py34 
$ conda install qt=4.8.7=vc10_4
```

**To Test**

*Make sure you have your py34 environment activated.*

```
$ spyder # will launch spyder
```

*In the Interactive Console in Spyder type:*

```
$ import cx_Oracle # the O in Oracle must be capitalized
```

If it doesn't error out, you're done!

My solutions were found mostly based on the following postings:

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2858

Comment: at `$ conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda` step after downloading some packages my command prompt is asking for **https user name and password**. What to do?

Comment: @poPYtheSailor are you behind a proxy? [this link](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server-proxy-servers) has instructions for configuration if so.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.5 binaries of cx_Oracle were made available on January 18. See here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. i am new to python and i don't know how to install the ".rpm" file on my windows machine. If you can help me out with that... it would be great help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to go to the web site noted in my answer and pick the .exe files, not the .rpm files (those are for Linux).